# Select in a cursor in DB2

Tags: database, db2

I have to fetch all columns names for all tables in a specific schema.

I did it without any problem in PL/SQL for an oracle Database but in DB2 I can't seem to make it work.

Here is my code :

```
BEGIN
declare cur1 cursor for
    select TABNAME 
    from syscat.tables 
    where tabschema = 'SchemaX';

open cur1;
fetch cur1 into i;
while SQLCODE <> 100
 do
   select * from SYSCAT.COLUMNS where tabname = i;
end while;
close cur1;
END
```

it doesn't seems to like my select in the while loop.

Anybody have done this before?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create one proc and then call it to get the result set.
Without creating procedure if you run it it will run but will give 0 zero results.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_PROC_FOR_TESTING
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
BEGIN
FOR I AS C1 cursor WITH HOLD for select TABNAME from syscat.tables where tabschema = 'SchemaX'
DO
BEGIN
DECLARE C_DISBURS_RPT CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CLIENT FOR
select * FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS where tabname =I.TABNAME;
OPEN C_DISBURS_RPT;
END;
END FOR;  
END!    

CALL MY_PROC_FOR_TESTING!
```

Note: End of the statement should be mentioned at the statement termination  box if it is IBM client.